# 4G not recognized by Reachability

Tags: ios, swift, reachability, internet-connection, reachability-swift

I'm using Reachability.swift from Ashley Mills (https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift). 
I use the following code to request the current network status:

```
do {
    reachability = try Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
} catch {
    print("Unable to create Reachability")
}

if reachability != nil {
    networkStatus = reachability!.currentReachabilityStatus
    print(networkStatus.description)
}
```

When running on a iPhone6 (no simulator) with 4G turned on, the network status is "No Connection" instead of "Cellular".

Can someone tell me what I am missing? Why is this not working correctly?

Comment: did you turn off mobile data for that app? check it in settings.

Comment: How simple can it be...! Thanks, that was the problem.

Comment: It might be off-topic because it was no programming problem, but the answer was very useful and can be useful for other users too, I think.